# How to create an animation with Folium?

Tags: python, pandas, folium

I am using Folium to create maps in Python.

I have a Pandas DataFrame where entries (latitude and longitude) are indexed by time. I would like to plot those entries one hour at a time (from 00:00 to 01:00 ...... from 23:00 to 00:00) in order to see the evolution of the of the locations on the map.

Is there a way to create an animation or video for such a purpose in Folium.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the TimestampedGeoJson plugin for this. See an example here:

https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/examples/Plugins.ipynb#Timestamped-GeoJSON

Comment: This works great...Is there a way to get the resulting movie saved as a mpeg or something similar that can be shared via email or similar?

Comment: I'm thinking your best bet is to use something to record your screen. Loads of options for that. Then share a video of you operating the map.

Comment: Ok, yeah, I was leaning in that direction but was hoping there might be a built in way

Comment: @Conengmo the link no longer works.

Comment: thanks for letting me know! Updated the link.